# Add Rows to Data of a View

Tags: sql-server

I have a view on my SQL Server that simply selects to columns from a table and has a third column, where several other columns are concatenated.

It looks somehow like this:

```
Group   Number   Text1
--------------------------
1       1        A unique desciption
1       2        Another unique one
1       3        This one is also unique
2       1        Here is something complete different
2       2        This is another unique text
```

and so on.

Now the view should also contain rows for each Group and Number 0. But these rows are not present in my given table and I cant add them, because the table is part of a third party application. The rows should contain the Text Values like the rows for the same group but with number 1.

So I want my view to look like this:

```
Group   Number   Text
-------------------------
1       0        A unique desciption
1       1        A unique desciption
1       2        Another unique one
1       3        This one is also unique
2       0        Here is something complete different
2       1        Here is something complete different
2       2        This is another unique text
```

How can I achieve this? I'm thankful for any hints!

Comment: A view doesn't *store* data - it's just a SQL statement that gets executed when you select from the view. You cannot *add* data to a view - the view's SQL statement selects the data from the underlying tables

Comment: Can you say your view.

Comment: Yeah I know that a view cant really store data, I just want to display the text for additional combinations of Group and Number. Isnt that somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this way : 
Include this concept inside the existing view or you this in a new view calling the current view.or run directly as a script

```
select group,number,text from view
union
select [group],0,min(text) from view group by [group]
```

order by as needed.

Comment: Okay this helps me! I am now at the point where I have added rows for each group with number 0. But the Textfield doenst simply contain 'Text 1 1', this was just a placeholder. It contains unique strings that cant be calculated. So I somehow have to select the Text from group 1 number 1 into the textfield for group 1 number 0. Is that possible?

Comment: I tried something like `select group,number,text from view
union
select distinct group,0, select text from view where view.group = group and view.number = 1 from view` but it doesnt work.

Comment: can you update the sample so i can help you out !
Is that you needed the first text from each group for the addedd lines?

Comment: I updated the example in the start post. I hope you understand it now. THe texts are unique desciptions. Im sorry I cant explain it better :-\ Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I have updated my answer. but cross check if this is giving only the first text in each group.I ll also check.Using Min will give you the first inserted text for that group.So hope you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that change calculate field in your view as following format:

```
Select Group, 
       Number, 
       'text ' + CAST([GROUP] AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' '+CASE WHEN Number=0 THEN '1' ELSE CAST(Number AS VARCHAR(10)) END as [Text]
From YourTable
```